# uitableviewcell custom background issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a grouped tableview where I have one row in each section. I am setting the backgroundview of the cell to my custom image and I wish the row is rendered this way:

[image]

But it renders like this (notice the absence of shadows, it's flat):

[image]

Here's the code in cellforRowAtIndexPath:

```
((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BGImage"];
```

Where BGImage is the first image in this post, with shadows. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set Your Cell Background using bellow Delegate Method of UITableView:-

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView
  willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell
forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];  // get your background image
            UIColor *backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage: img];
            cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

}
```

at your issue may be your image `Height` `width` and your cell `height` `width` not same

I am using above method in my project set with bellow shaded image set in Cell:-

[image]

and its look like in project :-

[image]

Comment: You are right! Except that in my case I needed cell.backgroundView to be set to an imageview containing my image. Renders fine now. Thanks for the willDisplayCell tip!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your shadow must be a part of your image.
2. You have to properly set the height and width.
3. I'd suggest you to create a custom `UITableViewCell`.
4. Add background image to your cell. It'll surely display the shadow.